# Rundeck Kerberos authentication unable to run command

Tags: windows, winrm, rundeck

Configuration and complete error:https://1drv.ms/t/s!AizscpxS0QM4hJo9MJWA6CKzd1BOwQ (too long for posting it here)

Rundeck is installed on CentOS machine, port 5955 opened on Windows server.Rundeck user is local admin on server

On Rundeck project

```
WinRM protocol:HTTP
HTTPS certificate trust:none
HTTPS server hostname verification:none
```

i'm getting this error (rest in link):

```
[overthere-winrm:192.168.0.13] failed: WinRM Error: Error when sending request to https://192.168.0.13:5986/wsman
Request:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <env:Header>
    <a:To xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">https://192.168.0.13:5986/wsman</a:To>
    <a:ReplyTo xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">
```

Answer (score 0):

didn't notice `winrm-protocol="https"` once changed it to `winrm-protocol="http"` in resource file, it started working